# Which is the correct way to measure the distance between inline and block elements?

Tags: html, css, typography

How should I, as a designer, document the margins between block elements and text in order to make a developers life easier and the build more accurate.

Is it correct to **a)** measure the empty space between the elements or **b)** include the line height of the text in our calculations?

a)

[image: Empty space between elements]

b)

[image: Line height included in calculations]

In the past I have always measured the empty space between the elements, documented it and sent it to the developers. However, when I myself have come to build from these designs I struggle to calculate the correct distance between things as the line height in CSS is calculated differently in Photoshop.

Comment: I think both solutions are correct, the important thing is to have the correct final space of the design.

Comment: So the question is, what does the designer expect? In the first picture, you measure the top element by its baseline and the bottom element by the extent of its line height. I don't think that is as it should be. Oh, and there is padding. Don't forget about the padding.